# Wpf gradient Equivalent of css Gradient

Tags: c#, css, .net, wpf, windows

Please what is the wpf equivalent of the following css gradient

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 27, from(#003489), color-stop(0.074, #003485), color-stop(0.111, #01358b), to(#003788));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [LinearGradientBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    LinearGradientBrush gradientBrush = new  LinearGradientBrush( Color.FromRgb( 0, 20, 54),  Color.FromRgb(0, 21, 55), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 27));
        Background = gradientBrush;
```

And although this isn't **exactly** what you asked, it should give you the guidance to get there! Happy coding